# What is the negative of 将会？

Tags: meaning

将会 (*Jiāng huì*) means 'will' and for its opposite meaning ('won't') I have seen 不将会 and 将不会.

Is there any difference here? Is one preferable to the other?

Comment: 将不会 sounds much better.

Comment: Would you say 不将会 is incorrect?

Comment: No, because occasionally I can hear 不将会 in a conversation. 不将会 does sound like badly organized in most situations, but the cause is probably the poetic effect of 不将会 with the subtly different meaning versus 将不会. For example, "他不曾会回来，所以也不将会离去" sounds logical, but "他不曾会回来，所以也将不会离去" does not. "将不会离去" in the second sentence presumes that "he is already here" but then it contradicts "他不曾会回来". In the first sentence, "不将会离去" doesn't have such a presumption.

Comment: @Stan "他不曾会回来，所以也不将会离去" sounds fine in poetic contexts (such as lyrics) but is certainly considered ungrammatical by middle school teachers.

Answer (score 3):

> negative of 将会 = 将不会 negative of 将。。。 = 将不。。。
>
> 将在这里举行 
>   将不在这里举行
>
> 将做详细说明 将不做详细说明

Answer (score 2):

`不将会` is not correct. You can say `将不会`.

> 如果你使用这种药物，你的所有症状将会消失。
>   如果你不使用这种药物，你的所有症状将不会消失。

And you can just say `不会` for `won't`.

> 如果你不使用这种药物，你的所有症状不会消失。

Comment: 在百度找到很多‘不将会’的例子。都错误的吗？

Comment: @Pedroski IMO, yes. `不将会` is so weird to me, that I can't figure out its meaning at the moment I see it. (After several seconds of thinking I can understand it...) BTW: I search `不将会` at bing.com and got only 45 results, while `将不会` has 1,740,000 results.

Comment: No problem, just asking, as my Chinese is so bad, I can't tell right from wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Actually we don't use 不将会 in daily life.because it is too wired. Even we rarely use 将不会 the expression, we feel more comfortable if you just use 不会 to tell us that you won't do something.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to make some add-up
1 将会 both 将 and 会 mean will, and we rarely use this in daily conversation. We sometimes use this in very formal articles such as news,documentary etc. For example: 新技术将会给我们的国家带来更多的活力。

2 The negative form of 将会 is 将不会。 For example：这个产品将不会出现在我们的网站上。

Hope  this could be of some help.